# Перенос слов в textarea

Tags: javascript, html

Как сделать перенос слов в текстовом поле?

Есть текстовое поле `textarea`, в него циклом выводится ряд слов. Необходимо чтобы каждое слово писалось с новой строки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем случае это выглядит так:

- Соединяем массив слов в одну строку с помощью `.join('&#13;&#10;')`
- `&#13;&#10;` используется для переноса строки.
- Выбираем `textarea` и устанавливаем результирующую строку в качестве её `.innerHTML`.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', onDomReady);

function onDomReady() {
    var words = ["One", "Two", "Three"];
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = words.join('&#13;&#10;');
};
```

```html
<textarea id="test"></textarea>
```